# Share a local printer in a remote session under Linux

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, terminal-server, printing

Do you know of an opensource equivalent of TSE under linux which can manage local printers?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by "remote session".

But look at ssh -R (forward a remote port to local one). That way, the remote machine can use a local (for it) port to connect to you CUPS server.